# How to deactivate BitLocker when it's not showing up in Control Panel

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, bitlocker, windows-11

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a new Dell with Windows 11. I have created the USB boot disk and want to install it alongside Windows 11 (rather than wiping W11). The installation goes well for the first half and then halts telling me that BitLocker needs to be deactivated.

I have logged back into Windows but there is no reference to BitLocker in the Device Encryption section of the Control Panel. The only device showing is OS (C): and the sole action available is 'back up your recovery key'.

I have done that in the hope it would change something, but nothing has changed. There is still nowhere to turn off BitLocker and I still get the same message when I try to install Ubuntu.

Comment: In an elevated command prompt run, `manage-bde -status`, and provide us the output as an edit to your question

Comment: To disable Bitlocker, in an elevated CMD enter: `manage-bde -off C:`. Save the backed up recovery key on an external disk, just in case.